# Is this site open to questions that are essentially requests for help classifying individual organisms?

Tags: discussion

I had several questions about the species of plant samples I took in Galveston, and I wanted to make sure such a thing would be on topic on this site.

Comment: could you give a link to that post (plant identification) here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes; [there isn't a complete consensus on whether these are ideal](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-for-the-identification-of-any-living-organism) but this type of question comes up quite frequently on the site (particularly for insects). If your question is about plant diseases, pests, or weeds it may be better suited to [gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) (the Gardening and Landscaping community). If you think Biology.SE is the best fit for your question please:

1. use high-quality photos where possible,
2. describe the collection site, and
3. make sure you include some idea of size (object in the
   photo for scale, for example).

Use the ['species-id' tag](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification).
And welcome to the site!

See also